# Python - Find all files containing specific text in directories and subdirectories using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, shell, grep, subprocess

I'm new to python.
i'm iterating through a set of  using **variable goods** i want to find list of files using specific text word **price** in the file to grep all files and read it.
I have the below codes but it gives **[Errno 2] no such files or directory**. if there are any other methods kindly someone guide me on this, Thanks in advance

```py
data=os.listdir('./data/pack/')
for goods in data:
    filepath = ('./file/'+ goods + '/cost/')
    grep=subprocess.Popen(['grep','-lir','price', filepath],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    found=grep.communicate()[0]
    print(found)
```

I even tried with some other method like below

```py
try:
    grep1=subprocess.Popen('[./file/'+ goods + '/cost/']), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    grep=subprocess.Popen(['grep','-lir','price'],stdin=grep1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep1.stdout.close()
    grep.communicate()
except
```

but none of the above 2 methods are giving me the result

Thank you!! **Result found!**

```py
cmd = 'grep -lir "price"' './file/'+ goods + '/cost/' -i | grep '.txt'
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Do you want to find files with the name **price** in it? Can you further explain?

Comment: @AmogChandrashekar To find all files which contains the text word 'price' in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively iterate through folders and subfolders, and get all the files with required extensions, in which you want to search.

```py
import os
from glob import glob

dir_path = "path_of_your_directory"
file_extension = "file_extensions_in_which_you_want_to_search"

files = [y for x in os.walk(dir_path) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.' + file_extension))]
```

Now iterate through files, open each file, and check for the text you want to search. You can search by using [find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) or using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```py
for file_path in files:
    if open(file_path, 'r').read().find('the_text_you_want_to_search') != -1:
        print("found")
```

Comment: Not working i'm getting Error as cant open file 'example.py' : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: see if i **grep -lir price** in a particular directory i will get all files. now i'm writing a script but i'm not getting how to use in subprocess.

Comment: Why are you using listdir twice? do you want to recursively find files inside sub directories as well?

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly, now check if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i found in grep cmd